# Generating a list of issues outside of conditions in VBA

Tags: vba

Brand new to VBA so just trying to get a general sense of approaches to use.

The following code defines an array and a condition set if a value is found that <> 0 then 'Failure'. Rather than stopping, I want to generate a list of columns where this condition is met.

Any tips or references would help. Thanks,

Sub validate()

```
Dim Arr1() As Variant
Dim num_rows As Long, num_columns As Long
Dim column_num As Long, row_num As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out").Select
    Arr1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out").Range("B15:CG66").Value
    num_columns = UBound(Arr1, 2)
    num_rows = UBound(Arr1, 1)
    For column_num = 1 To num_columns
        For row_num = 1 To num_rows
                            If Abs(Arr1(row_num, column_num)) > 0.001 Then MsgBox "Failure"
        Next row_num
    Next column_num
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: `Debug.Print row_num, column_num` will print to the immediate window, but depending on how many occurrences you may not get a complete list. You could also make notes on another sheet, or write to a text file, or build a new array... What sort of output are you looking for? Is this a permanent feature of your code or are you doing this for testing purposes?

Comment: Eventually Im going to generate an email to coworkers. That email code is already set I just need to incorporate my stuff. So I'm basically just messing around trying to learn VBA. I figure I probably just want to make notes on another sheet. Eventually, instead of referencing the columns I would specify a certain cell in each column as an identifier to the location of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have tweaked your code slightly (Since you are using `With` you don't need to keep spelling out `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out")`). This will generate a list of Column/Row to your Immediate Window

You were close already to this. You might want to try adding a function that will return the Column Letter from the column number you have.

```
   Sub validate()
    Dim Arr1() As Variant
    Dim num_rows As Long, num_columns As Long
    Dim column_num As Long, row_num As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tie Out")
        Arr1 = .Range("B15:CG66").Value
        num_columns = UBound(Arr1, 2)
        num_rows = UBound(Arr1, 1)
        For column_num = 1 To num_columns
            For row_num = 1 To num_rows
                                If Arr1(row_num, column_num) <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Column " & column_num + 1, "Row " & row_num + 14
            Next row_num
        Next column_num
    End With

    End Sub
```

An alternate method, which is how I would have done it is provided below:

```
Sub validate2()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Worksheets("Tie Out").Range("B15:CG66")
        If c.Value <> 0 Then
            'add your code here
            Debug.Print "Value not = 0 at cell address " & c.Address
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```